# How to fix Windows 10 incoming SMB session being RST'ed

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, smb, smbclient

I have computer A and B, both Windows 10 1703 (15063) with all updates installed up to now. I want to view A's SMB shares from B, but B says it cannot connect to A. Further investigation shows A is RSTing B's TCP connections to port 445.

Have tried:

- reboot everything
- allow "File and Printer Sharing" and "HomeGroup" from A's firewall
- resetting firewall of A
- disabling firewall of A
- disabling firewall of router
- connecting using IP address
- using wired or wireless connection
- using Windows 7 or Windows 10 to connect

And nothing works.

Note:

- `nc A 445` from a Linux host got immediate RST
- A can connect to other SMB shares
- A didn't show up in `net view /all` on B but it shows up in Network option in explorer
- visiting `\\localhost` on A works
- the network A connected to is set to private network

Wireshark capture:
[image: Wireshark result]
(A is .26 and B is .34; left 2 masked column is my LAN IP network number; all masked region on the right are either NetBIOS name of A or IP of A.)

Windows SMB config

```
Get-SmbServerConfiguration


AnnounceComment                 :
AnnounceServer                  : False
AsynchronousCredits             : 64
AuditSmb1Access                 : False
AutoDisconnectTimeout           : 15
AutoShareServer                 : True
AutoShareWorkstation            : True
CachedOpenLimit                 : 10
DurableHandleV2TimeoutInSeconds : 180
EnableAuthenticateUserSharing   : False
EnableDownlevelTimewarp         : False
EnableForcedLogoff              : True
EnableLeasing                   : True
EnableMultiChannel              : True
EnableOplocks                   : True
EnableSecuritySignature         : False
EnableSMB1Protocol              : True
EnableSMB2Protocol              : True
EnableStrictNameChecking        : True
EncryptData                     : False
IrpStackSize                    : 15
KeepAliveTime                   : 2
MaxChannelPerSession            : 32
MaxMpxCount                     : 50
MaxSessionPerConnection         : 16384
MaxThreadsPerQueue              : 20
MaxWorkItems                    : 1
NullSessionPipes                :
NullSessionShares               :
OplockBreakWait                 : 35
PendingClientTimeoutInSeconds   : 120
RejectUnencryptedAccess         : True
RequireSecuritySignature        : False
ServerHidden                    : True
Smb2CreditsMax                  : 2048
Smb2CreditsMin                  : 128
SmbServerNameHardeningLevel     : 0
TreatHostAsStableStorage        : False
ValidateAliasNotCircular        : True
ValidateShareScope              : True
ValidateShareScopeNotAliased    : True
ValidateTargetName              : True

sc.exe query mrxsmb20

SERVICE_NAME: mrxsmb20
        TYPE               : 2  FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

sc.exe query lanmanworkstation

SERVICE_NAME: lanmanworkstation
        TYPE               : 30  WIN32
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ramhound Why is this happening and how can I fix this (apparently I need to get SMB working...)

Comment: You should update your question.  Do you have SMBv2 and SMBv3 enabled on both clients?

Comment: @Ramhound updated my question and added some more details. Both SMBv2 and SMBv3 is enabled according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, with the exact same wireshark trace.. then I realized that the IP was incorrect, and a Linux server --obviously without SAMBA-- was sending the RST,ACK packets. So the reason could be that :

- You typed the wrong IP / DNS name
- No service listening on server side